# problem uploading files using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a crud application that uses the following functions to update the data on a Google Sheet and create PDF files from them

```
function doGet(e) {
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('WebAppBoot');
    }
    
    function UpdateRecord(seqId, name, personId,curr_degree, up_curr_court, tmp_court, curr_specialization, needed_specialization,member_place_of_residence,required,work_2020,work_2021,work_2022,mobile_no,whatsapp_no,home_no,email,languages,school,college,high_edu,comments,pathological_excuse,batch,work_2023) {
      var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA"); 
      var seq_id = parseInt(seqId);
    function searchRecords(personId,password)
    {
      var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA"); 
      var getLastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();
      var returnRows = [];
      var readIds = [];
      var passcode = 0;
      if (personId == '')
      {
        return returnRows;
      }
```

I need to use the following function to upload data to the Google Drive account

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N1mygodDf6e-i3QCX1wm5Fh3UV1uKiNL3BX1RnC4NhU/edit#gid=0'
var sh = 'FILE'
var folderId = '1lIG33NoNyzzziD0uUcS1zsOQQ73934U0'

var superscript = SuperScript.initSuper(url,sh)
var formObject = {}
formdata.forEach(element => formObject[element.name] = element.value)
var file = superscript.uploadFile(folderId,formObject.myfile.data,formObject.myfile.name)
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
var ws=ss.getSheets()[0]
 ws.appendRow([
   new Date(),
  formObject.name,
  "'"+formObject.ticket,
  formObject.boarding,
   file.getUrl()
 ]);
}'
```

Whenever I do this the application blacks out, I need also to add the following upload button to the linked HTML

```
displayTable += "<td><div style=\"padding: 60px\"> ";
       displayTable += "<input type=\"button\" id=\"update_button"+ row_number +"\" value=\"upload \" class=\"btn btn-primary\"";
       displayTable += "onclick=\"UpdateRecord("+row_number+")\" /></div> ";
       displayTable += "</td>";
       displayTable += "</tr>";
       row_number++;  
       }  
     });
```

The HTML WebAppBoot is as follows

```
function showModalMsg(outputText)
    {
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      document.getElementById("modal_body").innerHTML= outputText;
      modal.style.display = "block";
      span.onclick = function() {modal.style.display = "none";}
    }
    function UpdateRecord(row_number)
    {
      var oldId = document.getElementById("personId").value;

      document.getElementById("update_button"+row_number).disabled = true;
      var seqId = document.getElementById("up_seqId"+row_number).value;
      var name = document.getElementById("up_name"+row_number).value;
      var personId = document.getElementById("up_personId"+row_number).value;
      var curr_degree = document.getElementById("up_curr_degree"+row_number).value;
      var up_curr_court = document.getElementById("up_curr_court"+row_number).value;
      var tmp_court = document.getElementById("up_tmp_court"+row_number).value;
      var curr_specialization = document.getElementById("up_curr_specialization"+row_number).value;
      var needed_specialization = document.getElementById("up_needed_specialization"+row_number).value;
      var member_place_of_residence = document.getElementById("up_member_place_of_residence"+row_number).value;
      var required = document.getElementById("up_required"+row_number).value;
      var work_2020 = document.getElementById("up_work_2020"+row_number).value;
      var work_2021 = document.getElementById("up_work_2021"+row_number).value;
      var work_2022 = document.getElementById("up_work_2022"+row_number).value;
      var mobile_no = document.getElementById("up_mobile_no"+row_number).value;
      var whatsapp_no = document.getElementById("up_whatsapp_no"+row_number).value;
      var home_no = document.getElementById("up_home_no"+row_number).value;
      var email = document.getElementById("up_email"+row_number).value;
      var languages = document.getElementById("up_languages"+row_number).value;
      var school = document.getElementById("up_school"+row_number).value;
      var college = document.getElementById("up_college"+row_number).value;
      var high_edu = document.getElementById("up_high_edu"+row_number).value;
      var comments = document.getElementById("up_comments"+row_number).value;
      var pathological_excuse = document.getElementById("up_pathological_excuse"+row_number).value;
      var batch = document.getElementById("up_batch"+row_number).value;
      var work_2023 = document.getElementById("up_work_2023"+row_number).value;

      

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(data => 
      {
        showModalMsg("تم تسجيل البيانات بنجاح");
        document.getElementById("update_button"+row_number).disabled = false;
        if (oldId != personId)
        {
          SearchRecords();
        }
        google.script.run.createDoc (name,curr_degree, up_curr_court, tmp_court, curr_specialization, needed_specialization,member_place_of_residence,required,work_2020,work_2021,work_2022,mobile_no,whatsapp_no,email,languages,school,college,high_edu,comments,pathological_excuse,work_2023);

      }).withFailureHandler(data => {showModalMsg("حدث خطآ فى عملية تسجيل البيانات");}).UpdateRecord(seqId, name, personId,curr_degree, up_curr_court, tmp_court, curr_specialization, needed_specialization,member_place_of_residence,required,work_2020,work_2021,work_2022,mobile_no,whatsapp_no,home_no,email,languages,school,college,high_edu,comments,pathological_excuse,batch,work_2023);

    }

    function SearchRecords() 
    {
      var personId = document.getElementById("personId").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      var row_number = 0;
      var tempTable1 =[];
      var tempTable2 =[];
      var tempTable3 =[];
      var tempTable4 =[];
      var tempTable5 =[];
      var i;
      var correctPass = true;

      document.getElementById("rowdata").innerHTML = "";

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) 
      {
        console.log(ar);

        var displayTable= "" ;
        ar.forEach(function(item, index) 
        {
          if (item[0] == -1)
          {
            correctPass = false;
          }
          else
          {
          displayTable = '<form>';
          displayTable += "<td><div style=\"padding: 10px\"></div></td>  ";
          displayTable += '<table class=\"table table-info table-borderless text-right\" dir=\"rtl\" id=\"mainTable\" >';

          displayTable += "<tr id=\"ROWNUMBER:"+ row_number +"\" >";
          displayTable += "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"up_seqId"+ row_number +"\" value=\""+item[0]+"\" /></div></div> ";
          
          displayTable += "<tr><td><div class=\"form-row\"><div class=\"form-group col-md-4\"><label for=\"up_name\">name</label> ";
          displayTable += "<input type=\"text\" id=\"up_name"+ row_number +"\" value=\""+item[1]+"\" class=\"form-control text-right\" disabled /></div> ";
    displayTable += "<td><div style=\"padding: 60px\"> ";
          displayTable += "<input type=\"button\" id=\"update_button"+ row_number +"\" value=\"إرسال البيانات \" class=\"btn btn-primary\"";
          displayTable += "onclick=\"UpdateRecord("+row_number+")\" /></div> ";
          displayTable += "</td>";
          displayTable += "</tr>";
          row_number++;  
          }  
        });

        if (correctPass == false)
        {
          document.getElementById("rowdata").innerHTML = "<p style=\"padding: 20px\">الرقم السري غير صحيح</p>";
        }
        else
        {
          if (displayTable == "")
          {
            document.getElementById("rowdata").innerHTML = "<p style=\"padding: 20px\">لا توجد بيانات مسجله بهذا الرقم القومى</p>";
          }
          else
          {
            displayTable += '</table></form>';
            document.getElementById("rowdata").innerHTML = displayTable;
          }

        }

      }).searchRecords(personId,password);
      
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="myModal" class="modal" >
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div id="myModalContent"class="modal-content" >
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <style>
  .modal{
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  }
  .modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: right;
   }
  .close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: left;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
  .close:hover,
  .close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
  </style>
   <p id="modal_body"></p>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div style="padding: 10px;" align="center" dir="rtl">
  <form>
  <label for="personId">ID : </label>
  <input type="search" id="personId" placeholder="Password please"  dir= "ltr" style= "width: 315px; hight: 20px;" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');" maxlength="14"/><br>

  <label for="personId">الرقم السري : </label>
  <input type="search" id="password" placeholder="ID  PLEASE"  dir= "ltr" style= "width: 315px; hight: 20px;"/><br>

  <input type="button" value="search" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="SearchRecords()"/>
  </form>
  <div id="rowdata"></div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>

    enter code here

i tried the previous code and it blacked out
```

Comment: can you clarify more about your error, desired output and if you can please include how you name your GS and HTML files. Just to confirm if this is also everthing for this project, It looks incomplete and might be the cause of your error.

Comment: Would you please supply `WebAppBoot.html`

Comment: Original code is sourced from [Create a Bootstrap Google Web Application Form on Google Sheets](https://codewithcurt.com/create-a-bootstrap-web-app-form-on-google-sheets-using-apps-script/) (codewithcurt.com)

Comment: i added most of the html to the question, thanks for helping

Comment: thanks for mentioning this but the code in the reference doesn't have an uploading button

Comment: please let me know if you want me to add something else

Comment: @user20795119, I have multiple thoughts about your post. I am struggling to replicate your problem in my end due to the following factors. Your HTML file has major flaws in its baser form, and it will require a complete overhaul to fix.  I am wondering as well as why you need to create the HTML file as you load it, if it is not you can start on there. Second, the error is still unclear about the black screen do you mean graphically? If that is, I would suggest removing scripts and building the base HTML first, then move forward. You have redundancy on the code as well.